# ASP MVC getting GET request instead of POST

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have next specific map routes

```
routes.MapRoute(
             "MyPagePost",
             "URL-Up/{name}",
               new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyPostAction" },
               new { httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
                );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "MyPageGet",
                "URL-Up/{name}",
                  new { controller = "MyController", action = "MyGetAction" },
                  new { name = "[A-Za-z].+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
           );
```

my default controller looks like

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { culture = @"[a-zA-Z]{2}" }
                );
```

and the issue is next:
 my get *MyPageGet* route show a page with include FORM with POST reqvest to *MyPagePost* route, but on a first call I am getting the same GET request and see in URL other extra param ?culture=de. Moreover, with or without this parameter, second call it working fine via  MyPagePost route.

UPDATE:
In Chrome or fiddler Logs I see that reqvest to  `URL-Up/Bla-Bla` has 302 status and response heared is *URL-Up/Bla-Bla?culture=de*. Why it can't be processed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try it with

```
@using(Html.BeginRouteForm("MyPagePost",FormMethod.Post))
{
     <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

The  routes in your post working for me in both html.beginform and html.beginrouteform on the first time.

i try it with the following routes and action methods

```
      routes.MapRoute(
          "MyPagePost",
          "URL-Up/{name}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "PostAction" },
            new { name="[A-Za-z].+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("POST") }
             );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "MyPageGet",
            "URL-Up/{name}",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "GetAction" },
              new { name = "[A-Za-z].+", httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint("GET") }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
             name: "Default",
             url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
             defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", culture = "en", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             constraints: new { culture = @"[a-zA-Z]{2}" }
             );

           public ActionResult GetAction()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PostAction()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: the result is the same

Comment: after different way I finally epiphany solve the issue I write the same controller method name MyGetAction with httppost attribute and it is working